# How to initiate animation only when in view - angular 12

Tags: angular

I'm using angular 12, with cli.
I want to make an animation that will happen only when the user scrolls to the HTML element.
any guidance on how to do it?

Comment: 1. What animate you want to achieve?
2. search html scrolling event in google

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.